# How to get index of an item in a array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

What is the most efficient way to get the index of an item in array? In Objective-C we used to be able to do:

```
[arrayName indexOfObject:myObject]
```

in Swift, I know we can do the following.

```
index =arrayName.indexOf({$0 === myObject})
```

is this the cleanest and most efficient way to do it?

Comment: As it stands, this question is primarily opinion-based.  Please elaborate on what you mean by "cleanest and most efficient."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Oliver pointed out, you can use

```
let index = array.indexOf(myObject)
```

However, this will only work if your object conforms to the `Equatable` protocol, to conform to it, you have to implement the `==` function, like this:

```
class MyClass {
}

extension MyClass: Equatable { }

func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs // === returns true when both references point to the same object
}
```

If your class inherits from `NSObject` and your comparison is something other than just comparing pointers, you'll have to override `isEqual:` as well

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  guard let obj = object as? MyClass else { return false }
  return self == obj
}
```

Comment: There is no need to override isEqual, each NSObject has it's own base implementation that checks for  pointers equality, you should only if you need to match something different than the value of the pointers

Comment: @Andrea you are right, I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
let index = array.indexOf(myObject)
```

You don't need to use the closure as indexOf accepts the element itself as an argument

Bear in mind that index is optional though

Comment: and that myObject must conform to Equatable and that it will return the index of the first match

Comment: Yes exactly, although the closure ronaldoh1 used requires this also.

Comment: I don't think so... Ronaldo used === the identity operator that is only valid for reference type and checks if the objects have the same references

Comment: Yes, indexOf requires a predicate it. (Still a bit confusing)

Comment: Ah yeah you are right for ===, but indexOf is equivalent to indexOfObject for an NSArray, if you wanted something in swift for indexOfObjectIdenticalTo I'm afraid your current solution is more than likely the cleanest way without extending CollectionType